# outputting the results of an sql query to group by day in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a list of classes stored in my database and i want to display them on my php page but in a way where each day is listed in order and the classes that run on that day are listed beneath. Something like so:

```
Monday
------
Class 1 - Venue - Time
Class 2 - Venue - Time

Tuesday
-------
No Classes

Wednesday
---------
Class 3 - Venue - Time
```

I am able to display the classes in order by day but i am unable to display them in groups as above.

the structure of my database table is

```
#   Name      Type  
1   link      varchar(40)           
2   idPrimary int(4)                         
3   location  varchar(40)   
4   town      varchar(15)
5   city      varchar(10)
6   day   enum('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',... 
7   starttime time                       
8   endtime   time               
9   age   enum('Childrens', 'Mixed', 'Adults')  
10  style     enum('Karate', 'Kickboxing', 'Womens Self Defense'...   
11  class     varchar(40)
```

My SQL is very basic at present

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_timetable` GROUP BY day, starttime";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

and the code i currently have to display the records is
[code]

```
        if($numrows > 0)
        {
            $i = 0;
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $venue = $row['location'];
                $town = $row['town'];
                $city = $row['city'];
                $day = $row['day'];
                $starttime = date("H:i",strtotime($row['starttime']));
                $endtime = date("H:i",strtotime($row['endtime']));
                $age = $row['age'];
                $style = $row['style'];
                $class = $row['class'];
                $link = $row['link'];
                if($i % 2 == 1)
                {
                    $math = "odd-row";
                }
                else
                {
                    $math = "even-row";
                }?>
                <div class="timetable-row <?php echo $math?>">
                    <div class="timetable-day">
                        <div class="tablet-heading">Day</div>
                        <div class="tablet-content"><?php echo $day?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timetable-venue">
                        <div class="tablet-heading">Location</div>
                        <div class="tablet-content"><?php echo $venue?><br /><div class="event-desc"><?php echo $town.", ".$city?></div></h4></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timetable-style">
                        <div class="tablet-heading">Discipline</div>
                        <div class="tablet-content"><?php echo $style?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timetable-age">
                        <div class="tablet-heading">Age Group</div>
                        <div class="tablet-content"><?php echo $age?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timetable-start">
                        <div class="tablet-heading">Start Time</div>
                        <div class="tablet-content"><?php echo $starttime?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timetable-end">
                        <div class="tablet-heading">End Time</div>
                        <div class="tablet-content"><?php echo $endtime?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timetable-link">
                        <div class="tablet-heading">Club Page</div>
                        <div class="tablet-content"><a href="<?php echo $link?>" title="<?php echo $town." club page";?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">More ></button></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div><?php
                $i++;
            }
        }?>
```

[/code]

i've just added the days array but not sure if i will need it or not?

Comment: Just start a new row if day has changed. Or what's the problem?

Comment: You probably don't actually want a `GROUP BY` in your query (even though you want the display to show them "grouped"), but instead you want an `ORDER BY`

Comment: thanks @PatrickQ i originally had ORDER BY which gave me an ordered list but was unsure how to display the classes in the desired way so i thought i'd try the  GROUP BY option. :)

Comment: To get the desired display formatting, simply apply the logic mentioned by freeek (check if the date of the current row is the same date as the previous, if not, start a new section).

Comment: sorry I'm clearly being dumb, within my php code above how do i check if the day is different to the previous record and if it is display a new day? the only way i can see how to do it is to run 7 separate queries one for each day of the week which probably isn't the best method.

Comment: `$row['day']` is the day of the current row, right?  And you want to take a certain action (start a new display section) when `$row['day']` changes, right? So at the end of the loop, assign that to a new variable, say `$prevRowDay`.  Then the next time through the loop, check `if(isset($prevRowDay) && $prevRowDay != $row['day'])`

Comment: ah i see, bliming simple when you put it like that :D thank you for explaining it for me